# Where should I ask questions about setting up phone systems on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

If I can’t ask [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1825683/how-do-i-connect-voip-service-to-pstn) on Network Engineering or Super User because it’s getting downvoted, where in the world am I supposed to ask this?

Please explain how this is off topic. There have been questions asked similar to this. I’m asking on Quora now, but please answer my last question before I leave.

Comment: “Please explain step by step what I would need to do and also include what I would need to buy and the cost.” - We don’t write tutorials nor do we recommend hardware here on Super User. If you have a specific question, like for instance, a single step of the setup of the hardware then we might be able to help. However, as currently stands, you don’t have the hardware or enough knowledge to ask a specific question about the setup

Comment: @Ramhound So then Quora it is. Stack Exchange is for specific questions

Comment: Quora answers in my experience are not free. Your welcome to ask your question there though.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I ended up asking it on Reddit. It’s better than Quora in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't do anything about the downvotes *but* I've messed around with the theory behind this and have a few observations.

I've done an edit that should have it in better shape, but I think this is one of those 'unfortunate' intersections of vaguely obscure technology and well, *people*.

I'd say its on topic, *but* most people don't know VOIP lingo (I can't find a good wikipedia page explaining FXO) - what you need might actually be something else entirely.

While its not off topic for us - I suspect a space that's more specific to people building VOIP systems and are familiar with the lingo and hardware might be better than quora.

Comment: So, when the question is offtopic, you just rewrite it to be ontopic? Hm.

Comment: Its essentially the same question - reworded a little as someone who has both a little knowledge of the topic, and the system. I also didn't reopen it, I left it for review.

Comment: Well, I'll vote to reopen but I still stand behind its original closure when it was about what hardware to buy and what that would cost...

Comment: What if we made a Stack Exchange site just for setting up phone systems?

Comment: Well , the new site creation process at the moment is completely broken so I wouldn't hold my hopes up

Comment: @Gantendo - Yes; That’s actually how every out of scope question should be handled. Obviously, if your mood or a hardware recommendations, that more difficult but there is a small union of recommendation and understanding say for instance Ray Tracing that could be within scope.